# Overwriting child link style properties inline

Tags: html, css, amazon-web-services, email, verification

I'm making an email template to be used with AWS. In the body text of the email we add a `{username}` variable which gets replaced by the user's actual username. In our case the username will be an email address and when Amazon works their magic it gets replaced with a `mailto:` link
e.g:

`<p>{username}</p>`

will become

`<p><a href="mailto:example@domain.com">example@domain.com</a></p>`

I want to be able to change the style of the link, but don't have access to the format of the `<a>` tag itself. Also because email clients don't widely recognise style tags I can't use CSS so all solutions must be inline.

I've tried:

`<p style="color: #fff !important"><a href="mailto:example@domain.com">example@domain.com</a></p>`

and that has no effect.

Any ideas very welcome!

[Fiddle for the sake of testing.](https://jsfiddle.net/mjf74z0L/1/)

Comment: you cant use !important inline and you shouldnt really use it anywhere else either

Comment: I understand that now, that's why I'm here asking for an alternative!

Comment: If you can only style inline there is no way to target a child element. Can you not add a <style> tag within the email/template?

Comment: Sorry just saw that you can not use style tags. Unfortunately there is no way around this then as its impossible to target a child element with inline style. Can you not have AWS only return the users email address and then code the link your self?

Comment: @GifCo I can add a style tag it just doesn't get picked up by some email clients, but if there's no other workaround that'll have to do. It doesn't look like it no, they just do some behind the scenes trickery and a link comes out. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: No problem, html email is not fun!! Good luck :)